# EJS cannot read property of undefined, how can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My site has broken between now and last night, even though I didn't change anything. I'm making a site which grabs weather data. It's based directly on a medium article here: https://codeburst.io/build-a-weather-website-in-30-minutes-with-node-js-express-openweather-a317f904897b

Here's the server js content...

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let city = req.body.city;
  let country = req.body.country;
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}${
    country.length > 0 ? "," + country : ""
  }&units=imperial&appid=${api}`
  request(url, function(err, response, body){
    if (err) {
      res.render('index',
      {weather: null, error: "Please Enter Valid Location"});
    }
    else {
      let weather = JSON.parse(body)
      if (weather.main == undefined) {
        res.render('index',
        {weather: null, error: "Please Enter  Valid Location"});
      }
      else {
        let content = {
          temp: weather.main.temp,
          city: weather.name,
          condition: weather.weather[0].description,
          icon: "svgs/" + weather.weather[0].icon + ".svg"
        }
        res.render('index', {weather: content, error: null});
      }
    }
  })
});
```

And here's the corresponding EJS templates...

```
<% if (locals.weather !== null){ %>
   <p><%= locals.weather.city %></p>
   <p><%= locals.weather.condition %></p>
<% } %>

<% if(error !== null){ %>
  <p><%= error %></p>
<% } %>
```

It worked last night, but now it's saying "Cannot read property 'city' of undefined".

Comment: try `<% if (locals.weather != null){ %>` which should handle `undefined`

Comment: @generalhenry, That did it, thanks. The person who wrote the tutorial made so many mistakes, and the people leaving comments kept correcting him.